# rs.next() to stop looping

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select pass from admin where nama='admin'");

if (rs.next()) {
    String n = rs.getString(1);

    if (n == nama) {
        Pegawai.setEnabled(true);
        InputCuti.setEnabled(true);
        DataCuti.setEnabled(true);
        DataCuti1.setEnabled(true);
        //in this part I want to stop the loop.
    } else {
        Pegawai.setEnabled(false);
        InputCuti.setEnabled(false);
        DataCuti.setEnabled(true);
        DataCuti1.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

While loop checks whether,there's an array of data next. If it's true loop continues else it stops.

Comment: just add a second varibale called stop that you set to false so if(rs,next&&stop==false)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Do **not** compare Strings with `==`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/330315

Comment: Also: you do not _have_ a `while` loop in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **break;** in your while loop.

```
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select pass from admin where nama='admin'");

while (rs.next()) {
    String n = rs.getString(1);

    if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(nama)) {
        Pegawai.setEnabled(true);
        InputCuti.setEnabled(true);
        DataCuti.setEnabled(true);
        DataCuti1.setEnabled(true);

        break; //when n==nama loop stops
    } else {
        Pegawai.setEnabled(false);
        InputCuti.setEnabled(false);
        DataCuti.setEnabled(true);
        DataCuti1.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```